# haproxy/apache/tomcat - no trailing slash results in a 301 redirection

Tags: apache-2.2, tomcat, haproxy

I have this configuration in place:

haproxy(80,443) --> httpd(8443) --> tomcat(8096)

Going to `https://websrv1/test` will result in a 301 redirect to the httpd port for which
haproxy should be proxying requests. 
So the user is redirected to `http://websrv1:8443/test`.

But, if the user goes to `https://websrv1/test/ - specifying a the trailing slash` - it works just fine.

How can I prevent this redirection from happening, when the user DOES NOT specify a trailing slash?

- haproxy configuration?
- apache url rewrite?
- tomcat url rewrite?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is on the Apache level.

You could try to set

```
UseCanonicalName On
```

and

```
ServerName websrv1:80
```

in your Apache config to make apache use the correct rewrite.

Alternatively you could disable the rewrite of the trailing slash with

```
DirectorySlash Off
```

See [UseCanonicalName](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#usecanonicalname), [ServerName](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#servername) and [DirectorySlash](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_dir.html#directoryslash)

Comment: Thanks. I tried all the options that you suggested and the problem persists.

Comment: It is possible that your browser has the redirects cached because the are set with a permanent redirect

Comment: Nope.. I tried after cleaning all caches.

Comment: I don't know if HAProxy caches rewrites. But that might be possible.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old post, but since I was struggling with this even in 2024 with tomcat 10.1 and tried too many options before it finally worked I decided to post what I've found.

**TLDR:**

Set `scheme="https"` in your `<Connector>` block. The issue originates from Tomcat.

**My road to this solution**

I had only found this question and one other: [Tomcat Trailing Slash With Proxy Forwarding](https://serverfault.com/questions/1020262/tomcat-trailing-slash-with-proxy-forwarding) but not much more on the topic.

Since we also have a mix of nginx/tomcat I couldn't find out who was doing the https to http redirect. I'll show what I've tried, they may work in your case if the above solution doesn't work.

- Attempt 1: Add `proxyPort="443"` to the `<Connector>` block. Failed in a miserable redirect to `http://hostname:443/path`
- Attempt 2: Added `mapperContextRootRedirectEnabled="false" mapperDirectoryRedirectEnabled="false"` to the `<Context>` block. Also tried with `true` but sadly nothing changed.
- Attempt 3: Set `useRelativeRedirects="true"` in the `<Context>` block. While this sounded very useful and actually worked when doing a request directly to tomcat (without nginx) giving a redirect `/path`. This does not seem to work when requesting via nginx. I really hope I figure this out some day.
- Attempt 4: Making sure it was really Tomcat's fault because the above setting worked locally. By setting `sendRedirectBody="true"` in the `<Context>` block made it obvious that it was tomcat since the response body now also contained the faulty redirect url.
- Attempt 5: Reading through all the options in https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-10.1-doc/config/http.html#Common_Attributes hoping to find something useful. As stated before this made me change  `scheme="https"` in the `<Connector>` block and the issue was gone.

Hope this saves someone else a headache.