# Tomcat Trailing Slash With Proxy Forwarding

Tags: apache-2.2, reverse-proxy, tomcat

I am running Tomcat 9 behind an Apache 2 server on Ubuntu 18. I am using a reverse proxy to send traffic to Tomcat with the following in the apache conf file:

```
ProxyPreserveHost On
ProxyPass "/"  "http://localhost:8080/MyApp/"
ProxyPassReverse "/"  "http://localhost:8080/MyApp/"
ProxyPassReverseCookiePath "/"  "http://localhost:8080/MyApp/"
ProxyPassReverseCookieDomain "/"  "http://localhost:8080/MyApp/"
```

Everything is working fine except one aspect. If the user omits the trailing slash on a subfolder then Tomcat redirects incorrectly. So for example:

https://www.mywebsite.com/login/

works fine, however if the user types

https://www.mywebsite.com/login

Tomcat will redirect to

https://www.mywebsite.com/MyApp/login/

It's sticking the MyApp folder into the redirect. Any ideas how to solve this?

Thanks

Comment: Use `AllowEncodedSlashes NoDecode` before ProxyPass and test

Comment: Thanks for the reply, unfortunately this did not solve the problem - any other ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old post, but since I was struggling with this even in 2024 with tomcat 10.1 and tried too many options before it finally worked I decided to post what I've found.

**TLDR:**

Set `scheme="https"` in your `<Connector>` block. The issue originates from Tomcat.

**My road to this solution**

I had only found this question and one other: [haproxy/apache/tomcat - no trailing slash results in a 301 redirection](https://serverfault.com/questions/528591/haproxy-apache-tomcat-no-trailing-slash-results-in-a-301-redirection/1153707) (Which I also answered with this answer) but not much more on the topic.

Since we also have a mix of nginx/tomcat I couldn't find out who was doing the https to http redirect. I'll show what I've tried, they may work in your case if the above solution doesn't work.

- Attempt 1: Add `proxyPort="443"` to the `<Connector>` block. Failed in a miserable redirect to `http://hostname:443/path`
- Attempt 2: Added `mapperContextRootRedirectEnabled="false" mapperDirectoryRedirectEnabled="false"` to the `<Context>` block. Also tried with `true` but sadly nothing changed.
- Attempt 3: Set `useRelativeRedirects="true"` in the `<Context>` block. While this sounded very useful and actually worked when doing a request directly to tomcat (without nginx) giving a redirect `/path`. This does not seem to work when requesting via nginx. I really hope I figure this out some day.
- Attempt 4: Making sure it was really Tomcat's fault because the above setting worked locally. By setting `sendRedirectBody="true"` in the `<Context>` block made it obvious that it was tomcat since the response body now also contained the faulty redirect url.
- Attempt 5: Reading through all the options in https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-10.1-doc/config/http.html#Common_Attributes hoping to find something useful. As stated before this made me change  `scheme="https"` in the `<Connector>` block and the issue was gone.

Hope this saves someone else a headache.